# Is it possible to use Java classes from the WEB-INF directory in Java agents

Tags: xpages

Currently I am busy with a brand new XPages project. I use Java and Managed Beans to access the data.
Till now I don't have to use Lotusscript ;-)

One of the last things is to create a scheduled agent to perform some backend stuff. There is already some logic in Java classes, who are in a directory in the WEB-INF directory.
I son't want rewrite these Java logic to Lotusscript, but reuse.

Is is possible to access these Java classes, from a (scheduled) Java agent??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe another option for you. I'll post on Monday sample code how to use Eclipse jobs on Domino triggered from XPages. These jobs can run on behalf of the current user. The Eclipse jobs framework also allows scheduling them.

Both XPages and your Eclipse jobs run in the http process and you can access the jobs from your XPages. In other words jobs can use the same code in the WEB-INF directory.

Teaser: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYgCfp1Bw8Q

Update: Posted the sample here http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/blogEntry.xsp?permaLink=NHEF-8SJB2R

Comment: Sounds cool indeed but also can introduce some nice issues when threads are deadlocked and so on.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that the WEB-INF directory that you are talking about is inside the NSF the answer is going to be NO.

Java Agents in Lotus Domino are self contained and can't see that part of the NSF. You could package those particular classes into a jar file and then attach the jar to the java agent or just copy the classes directly to the java agent. Either way you will have to maintain two sets of code.

Comment: I had asked similar question of XPages forum. There are alternatives suggested in this discussion. 

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=E89573775690EC9C85257840001DC328

Answer (score -2):

Yes, if the WEB-INF/classes is on the classpath when the java agent executes.  The other way to do it would be to put the classes in there own jar, and distribute the jar with the webapp and the java agent code.

Comment: This question is related to XPages on a Lotus Domino server, and the WEB-INF directory within a Lotus Notes database. The answer by Declan Lynch is the correct answer