# import ext lib class to my schedule java agent

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Is it possible to `import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil.*` class to my schedule java agent?

Thank you
leon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Just unpack the *updateSite* ZIP file and import the JARs in the agent.
I don't know what you are trying to do, maybe this is going in the wrong direction (the most functionality uses the "XPages classes" etc).

Have a look here for a better idea:
[Is it possible to use Java classes from the WEB-INF directory in Java agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726147/is-it-possible-to-use-java-classes-from-the-web-inf-directory-in-java-agents)